# borderBottomRightRadius not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to add a border radius only on bottom right of my `ImageBackground`, in docs it's pretty straight forward on how to do it. I've tried applying on `View` as well, but nothing changed.

I need to do that:

[image]

A piece of code where I used:

```js
 profileHeader:{
              width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
              height: 300,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              borderBottomRightRadius: 60,
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
            }
```

Any ideas of what is wrong?

And, anyone can give me a light on how to do that half avatar inside and outside?

Comment: can you provide an expo snack link for the same so that i can check and suggest?

Answer (score 0):

ive used your styling and can see the bottom border radius. please find the expo snack [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/Sy30Pbl5H) . Feel free to ask any doubts